# Failed to print variable after call to Session()

Tags: tensorflow

I have seen working examples like the following:

```
# GOOD CODE

import tensorflow as tf

# Build a graph.
a = tf.constant(5.0)
b = tf.constant(6.0)
c = a * b

# Launch the graph in a session.
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()

# Evaluate the tensor `c`.
print(sess.run(c))
```

This is fine. I think I get it. Building the graph simply defines the graph architecture but doesn't execute the graph. Execution only happens when the session is called. But then I thought that the following would work:

```
# BAD CODE 

import tensorflow as tf

# Build a graph.
a = tf.constant(5.0)
b = tf.constant(6.0)
c = a * b

# Launch the graph in a session.
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()

# Evaluate the tensor `c`.

sess.run(c)
print(c)
```

But it doesn't, all I see is...

```
Tensor("mul:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

...and I can not work out why. I have two ideas:

**Idea 1:** Maybe somehow the variable c only existed within the context of the session and somehow expired the moment sess.run(c) was completed? Can the code be modified such that the variable c is kept alive after the sess.run(c) call?

**Idea 2:** Somehow TF thought - "this guy is not doing anything with c (at least not immediately) so I'm not going to execute anything right now"... and so c has not been evaluated at all.

Comment: `c` is an operation object defined in a graph. When you print `c` you print the object not the result. It's the same thing as if you have some `class A` and you print it. You will get its memory location and other info. If you want to get the result of operation you're supposed to run it with `sess.run` method like you did. The method will return the evaluated result. You're supposed to do `c_result = sess.run(c)` and print `c_result`. For future reference it's better to ask this on stack overflow.

Comment: @Brale_ I think your comment should be the answer for this one. - If I hadn't read the comments I would have written the same thing but as an answer.

Comment: @Mick Note in tf2, its dynamic rather than generating a static graph (unless forced otherwise) and each tensor will have a numpy attribute associated with it.

Comment: Hi Mick! This question seems to be only about TensorFlow. This website focuses on answering conceptual and philosophical questions related to AI. We still accept some implementation-related questions, but, in your case, the question is only related to the inner workings of TensorFlow, which is a general computational tool, which can also be used by non-AI people. Please, ask this question on Stack Overflow (I will be glad to answer it there). See also https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.